# Capacitive touchscreens dangerous and piezoelectric

Tags: capacitance, touchscreen

Isn't capacitive touchscreen dangerous? I mean we are using our body to be a conductor and even with small voltages a current that could kill us.

Also why aren't piezoelectric touchscreens used? In the Wikipedia article there is no reference to a piezoelectric touchscreen but I guess it could work or is it more complicated than other forms of same technology?

Comment: "Capacitive" means "no DC path through this device"

Comment: Brian Drummond true capacitors eventually block dc but not always (until it is charged).

Comment: There are literally billions of capacitive touch screens in daily use with no reported cases of any kind of injury related to them. Does that tell you something about their safety?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean we are using our body to be a conductor and even with small voltages a current that could kill us

Not really; the body isn't used as a conductive path. You may have noticed that capacitative touchscreens work just fine on mobile phones, even when the phone has an insulating body and is touched by a single finger. There's no *loop* for current to flow in.

Instead the changing electric field of the touchscreen is used to measure the presence of the *dielectric* properties of the body. This may induce a very small current, but it is local to the finger, and there is no detectable risk associated with it.

(Risks are related to the amount of power dissipated and whether the current runs near the torso; humans can withstand large voltage small power shocks quite easily, which is why we don't drop dead when walking on nylon carpets)

Piezo touchscreens do exist but seem to be rare; I've no information on them and they weren't mentioned last time I needed to evaluate some vendors.

There are also optical touchscreens which detect the change in refraction from finger contact. Tend to be larger; the only manufacturer I'm aware of is [FlatFrog](https://www.flatfrog.com/), because I had a tiny part in the design of their system.

Answer (score 3):

1. A capacitive touchscreen has numerous transparent conductive stripes under the glass. A low AC voltage is between these stripes. If you finger is somehow near a pair of stripes it slightly increases the capacitive current between those stripes and that's registered by the control electronics (which must have some really smart algorithm to calculate the place of the finger reliably). If the glass gets broken you can get max few volts to your fingers. And it comes through resistors. It's not considered dangerous. 100V or more without current limiting high resistance circuit in series could be totally different.
2. I guess touchscreen manufacturers do not know how to make profit with piezoelectric touchscreens. At least it needs some force and bending to work and that's a bad thing. Materials must stand that stress. Capacitive touchscreens need no mechanically moving parts.